# Can I use Blazor Webassembly app on zero-client systems?

Tags: performance, virtualization, blazor-webassembly, kvm, thin-client

I'd like to develop a Blazor WASM for a company. This company uses the zero-client and virtualization to providing OS for users.
Blazor WebAssembly run your application as web assembly binaries directly in the browser and so use more resources from client system.

So, can it run on zero-client system at all?
If it can be implemented, can this reduce the performance of hundreds of zero-client and consume a lot of CPU and memory from KVM machine?

Client OS: Windows 10
Virtualization: KVM Linux
Server Memory: 256 GB

Comment: Define "zero-client". That's a demonstrably false marketing term. Browsers are clients. VMWare and Citrix clients are still clients, and pretty fat too. Running a virtual desktop on a server requires **A LOT** more power than running a browser on a client machine - which you need anyway. You won't be able to run more than a dozen or so virtual desktops on that server, especially since it uses a less optimized host. You'll have to buy the actual client machines *and* enough servers to host virtual desktop for all those machines. And another one for the web server.

Comment: That said, yes, Blazor WASM can run anywhere a browser can run. But that's not your real question. It looks like your real question is which architecture to pick so you can maximize the number of VDs per server. *It depends* on the type of application you really need. A server-rendered web app, eg one written using ASP.NET Core Razor Pages would use the least browser resources, putting a heavier load on the network and web server. A full SPA in React, Angular, Vue or Blazor WASM would put a greater load on the browser but require a lighter server. Blazor Server-Side sits between the two